# How to stop pm2 web command?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I thought `pm2 web` will give me nicer UI but it's just JSON API only.

In documentation it's not clear how can I stop this service running on port `9615`.

Is there any command like `pm2 stop web`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found it. Firing pm2 web command creates one more app and starts it. 
So to stop that process it's very easy command now.

```
pm2 stop pm2-http-interface
```

That's It !!!

[image: pm2 status]